# can not connect to docker container mapping port

Tags: mongodb, docker

I use mongo image in docker, but I can not connect to 20217 port.

docker@default:~$ docker ps

prot info show: 0.0.0.0:20217->20217/tcp, 27017/tcp

but,

gilbertdeMacBook-Pro:~ gilbert$ lsof -i tcp:20217

there is no PID,

gilbertdeMacBook-Pro:~ gilbert$ docker info

```
Containers: 3
Images: 43
Server Version: 1.9.1
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 50
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 4.1.13-boot2docker
Operating System: Boot2Docker 1.9.1 (TCL 6.4.1); master : cef800b - Fri Nov 20 19:33:59 UTC 2015
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 1.956 GiB
Name: default
ID: MRAZ:ZG5E:HDMY:EJNQ:HFL4:PW6Y:AXIS:6JFL:PFI5:GBAY:5SMF:NYQR
Debug mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 25
 Goroutines: 44
 System Time: 2016-01-27T14:53:52.005531869Z
 EventsListeners: 0
 Init SHA1:
 Init Path: /usr/local/bin/docker
 Docker Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker
Username: gilbertgan
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
 provider=virtualbox
```

Comment: the docker command shows 20217, but your lsof is on 27017

Comment: Are you running `docker-machine`?

Comment: I copy wrong, i fixed the question. yes , i was running docker-machine , it's ip is 192.168.99.100, and i also try: mongo 192.168.99.100:20217

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this is because on MAC  docker-machine is running on VM,so we need add the VM IP when connect to container. 
the ip can be show by: docker-machine ls

Comment: `docker-machine ip default` will give you the IP-address and can be used in scripting, e.g. `curl http://$(docker-machine ip default)`

Answer (score 0):

Your docker container maps port 20217 which isn't the MongoDB default port. The correct port is `27017`. And gilbert_gan is right as well. When running docker on docker-machine the docker host is not localhost but rather the virtual machine under docker-machine control.